# Caused by: com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 400 Bad Request POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to get bucket from GCP. I'm getting this problem. error“:”invalid_scope“,”error_description“:”Invalid OAuth scope or ID token audience provided."

```
public String uploadImage(String fileName , String filePath,String fileType) throws IOException {
   Bucket bucket = getBucket("serviceRequests");
    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));
    Blob blob = bucket.create(fileName, inputStream, fileType);
    return blob.getMediaLink();
  }

  private Bucket getBucket(String bucketName) throws IOException {
      Collection<String> ar=new ArrayList<String>();
      ar.add("https://storage.googleapis.com/saffrontest");
      
     GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream("/home/sparity/Downloads/Inhabitr Apps-3009206a82c0.json")).createScoped(ar);
    Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(credentials).build().getService();
   // Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setHost("https://storage.googleapis.com/saffrontest").build().getService();
    Bucket bucket = storage.get(bucketName);
    if (bucket == null) {
      throw new IOException("Bucket not found:"+bucketName);
    }
    return bucket;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error description suggests, no scopes or invalid scopes were detected while processing the GoogleCredentials (https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account).
Since you are explicitly trying to pass your service account file in code, I would suggest going through the scope URLs for Cloud Storage (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#oauth-scopes).

It seems that 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform' would work instead of 'https://storage.googleapis.com/saffrontest'. For a working exaple please refer to the last link (https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#passing_code
)